# Mono profiler "The 'log' profiler wasn't found in the main executable nor could it be loaded from 'mono-profiler-log'."

Tags: mono, profiling, profiler

I have an app on windows which runs on mono pretty fine. However when I try to profile it:

> mono --profile=log program.exe

I get:

> The 'log' profiler wasn't found in the main executable nor could it be loaded from 'mono-profiler-log'.

and no data file is created (but the app runs fine). Mono 3.0.10

Any ideas?

Comment: I get the same thing. Happening on OS X with MONO 3.0.12.

Comment: Same. Windows with Mono 3.2.3

Comment: Myself as well, Mono 3.2.2

Comment: Mono 3.8.0, compiled for Windows. Same issue.

Comment: @kei I read a bug report that said it may be due to llvm support, can you compile without llvm and then see what happens?

Comment: @Kel - I read a bug report that said that the issue was related to the llvm support (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=16785). Is it possible to build mono without that support?

Comment: I'm having this problem with 3.10.0 on openSUSE 13.1. Starting a bounty.

Comment: Compiling Mono without LLVM support did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @Owen Perhaps you should try mono bug tracker, it seems no one pays attention here :( It's not my first mono question, which is a bit tumble weeded ...

Comment: @ren I thought since others are having this problem with different releases of Mono and different platforms that it must be something I'm doing wrong rather than a Mono bug. I assume you never found a solution?

Comment: @Owen Nope (apart from switching to .net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set your dynamic library path.

**This works on OSX:**
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib
 mono --profile=log:calls program.exe

**In case of OpenSUSE :**

You need to use a third party profiler for which you must pass the name of the profiler to Mono, like this:

```
mono --profile=custom program.exe
```

As per above Mono will load the user defined profiler from the shared library **‘mono-profiler-custom.so’**.

This profiler module must be on your dynamic linker library path. A list of other third party profilers is available from Mono’s web site (www.mono-project.com/Performance_Tips).

Custom profiles are written as shared libraries. The shared library must be called ‘mono-profiler-NAME.so’ where ‘NAME’ is the name of your profiler

Comment: You need to use a third party profiler for which you must pass the name of the profiler to Mono, like this: mono --profile=custom program.exe
As per above Mono will load the user defined profiler from the       shared library ‘mono-profiler-custom.so’.  This profiler module must be       on your dynamic linker library path.
A list of other third party profilers is available from Mono’s web site       (www.mono-project.com/Performance_Tips). Custom profiles are written as shared libraries. The  shared  library must be called ‘mono-profiler-NAME.so’ where ‘NAME’ is the name of your profiler.

Comment: Thanks! The tip about the shared library name helped me figure it out. I didn't have the relevant .so file on my system because I was missing the mono-devel package. After installing that package I now have a working profiler! Can you please add an answer similar to your above comment so I can award the bounty to it?

Comment: There's a 24 hour grace period to award the bounty after it expires.

Comment: Is there a similar approach for Windows?

Answer (score 8):

I found that I got the same message on Ubuntu because I hadn't installed the `mono-profiler` package via `apt-get`.

Comment: I can seem to find such package anymore, is it discontinued?

Comment: @kuskmen Have you added the mono ppa?

Answer (score 0):

I was having same error message when trying to profile mono app on Linux machine which only had mono runtime installed. Additionally installing `mono-dev` package fixed it.